# How to save stores selector result to database in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, multistore, grid, store-view

I'm creating a simple CRUD with fields that should be configurable for store views. How should I save result of multiple store view selector? Should I serialize the array and save all store_views in one column, keep field for every store in separated records, or maybe use some sort of EAV?

[image: Store Views Selector]

I probably should keep it just like cms_block and cms_block_store are kept, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can saved it by comma separator or serialize into database. But it will be arise big problem when you pick data by store wise in front-end. So create a store table that should be one to many relation between main table and store table.

You can follow cms page/block process.

In that case you need to care about when save/load data and load collection.

Comment: Could you provide a quick steps (or files/methods to create) list how to save request to table x_y and store links in x_y_store?

Comment: For save and load-> https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/ResourceModel/Page.php

Comment: For collection -> https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/ResourceModel/Page/Collection.php

Comment: Magento 2.1 use same thing but using EntityManager which is messy. So use M2.0.x as an example.